# Vue click and iOS Safari

Tags: ios, vuejs2, mobile-safari

I have problem with toggling my hamburger menu. It works good everywhere except iOS Safari browser.

I have such markup:

```
<label for="menu" class="toggle-menu-icon" 
       @click="responsiveMenuShow">
</label>
```

and such code:

```
data() {
    return {
         responsiveMenuShown: false
    }
},
methods: {
responsiveMenuShow() {
      this.responsiveMenuShown = !this.responsiveMenuShown;
    }
}
```

Does someone have the same problem?

Comment: The code is okay, it's something else affecting, probably CSS. Although do you have something with `id="menu"`?

Comment: It's unnecessary id